# Delete or mark, record with max date in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, duplicates, databricks

I am new to data bricks, and I am trying to get rid of duplicate records for column "Patient_id" in a DF by using the "drop duplicate method.

I'm wondering if there is a way to delete duplicate records in the patient_id column depending on the time_stamp column, which is another column in DF.

So what I basically want is to keep the patient_idrd, which has the maximum time stamp, when Iop duplicates, and then delete the rest.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please add some code with sample input and expected output? Patient_id is a bit confusing

Comment: Use window operations with filtering to select only max timestamp inside the window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use window functions. You can define row_number based on descending date for each PatientID. Then filtering the records wherever row_number = 1, i.e., for each patient id select the maximum date and filter only those records.

```
date = ['2022-10-16 17:00:00', '2022-10-16 18:00:00', '2022-10-16 21:00:00', '2022-10-16 22:00:00']
id = [1, 1, 2, 2]
df = spark.createDataFrame(list(zip(id, date)), ['id', 'dt'])

import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

df = df.withColumn("rn", F.row_number().over(
    Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy(col("dt").desc())
))
df.where("rn = 1").select("id","dt").show()
```

Output -

```
+---+-------------------+
| id|                 dt|
+---+-------------------+
|  1|2022-10-16 18:00:00|
|  2|2022-10-16 22:00:00|
+---+-------------------+
```